# How to detect really IE when changed user agent

Tags: php, internet-explorer, user-agent

In my project have use `PHP` to detect browser, but my customers used `IE11` and change User agent to `IE7`. And my customer required detect is `IE11`, not `IE7`.
[image: IE 11]

Please help me detect really IE11

Comment: Why is your user changing their user agent string to that of IE 7?

Comment: maybe other site use agent string IE7. I don't known.

Comment: What the user is reporting is *by design*. Changing the ua-string is **supposed** to make the server think the user is on IE 7. This is largely for testing purposes, or to get around badly-written browser sniffing. The user is unlikely to have any valid reason for browsing the web with the developer tools opened, so that they can use a false ua-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check using JS

```
function checkIE()
    {
        var ieVr = -1;
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
        {
            var agent = navigator.userAgent;
            var exp = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (exp.exec(agent) != null)
                ieVr = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        }
        else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
        {
            var agent = navigator.userAgent;
            var exp = new RegExp("Trident/.*ieVr:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (exp.exec(agent) != null)
                ieVr = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
        }
        return ieVr;
    }
```

As per Doug in PHP

```
preg_match('/MSIE (.*?);/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
if(count($matches)<2){
  preg_match('/Trident\/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}; rv:([0-9]*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
}

if (count($matches)>1){
  //Then we're using IE
  $version = $matches[1];

  switch(true)
    {
    case ($version<=8):
      //IE 8 or under!
    break;

    case ($version==9 || $version==10):
      //IE9 & IE10!
    break;

    case ($version==11):
      //Version 11!
    break;

    default:
      //You get the idea
    }   
}
```

Comment: but this is JS, in PHP?